How to detect column name from current cell in an Excel table?
In an event triggered macro
Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
I need to offer the user the possibility to insert a value generate by another macro. However this should only take place in one certain column of the table.
For sure I can detect the current cell's column with
Target.Column
but this just gives me the numeric columns adress relative to the entire sheet. If my Excel table does not start on first column A, then this value does not match the index number of my coumn relative to the Excel table.
I have sought in object
Target.ListObject
but this does not seem to have something like "CurrentColumName".
For sure I could detect the range of the table and with a couple of calculations find out the header lable of the current column, but isn't there a more easy way to tell me "in which column (name) of the current Excel table (if any) my target cell is located?"
My current solution reads:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value = "" Then Call MyContentGenMacro() End If End Sub
But this relates to the fixed columns number 7 relative to the worksheet and not the the Excel table. So if I would move my table by one column, the macro would fail.
Any solution ideas anyone?
Trying to detect the field header from the current (=target) cell if located in an Excel table, but I only can detect the absolute column number relative to the worksheet.

Something like:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.ListObject Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Intersect(Target.EntireColumn, Target.ListObject.HeaderRowRange) = "Your desired Column Header" Then
            
       MsgBox "Run your macro"

        End If
    End If
End Sub




Thanks Ron, that's exactly what I needed but I would not have com to the idea of using that intersect() function, but it makes sens for sure.
Now it is working fine independent on absolute table position.
Thanks a lot!

@user16456933Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See What should I do when someone answers my question.
